# Javascript real-time countdown (count from Start to End time)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I do have the countdown script (see link below) to display the time between current time and the date given in real-time.

However, I want to achieve to display the time difference between a given start and end time. Right now, it calculates from the current server time to the end time.

I want to be able to set up my own start time and end time.

Here is what I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/BgEtE/

thank you for help :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems quite simple. untilYear has date and time information, so does sinceYear. Using the default constructor function results in a Date which points to the current millisecond (on the client), but the string constructor allows you to add the time after the date. Use this to specify your own start / end times. By the way, this does not work with server time, it works with client time. An important distinction.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://keith-wood.name/css/jquery.countdown.css" />
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="defaultCountdown" class="countdown"></span>
<script>
var untilYear = new Date(2011, 07, 26, 11, 20, 00);
var sinceYear = new Date(2010, 07, 26, 11, 20, 00);

$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ since: sinceYear, until: untilYear, compact: true, timezone: -4});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit: fixed. Added `sinceYear` as an argument to the countdown stuff. Previously it only had `untilYear`. Also changed the date format. It goes as thus (this is the most reliable constructor):

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

The other format kept breaking. If you need a different timezone, modify the timezone attribute.

```
    timezone: null, // The timezone (hours or minutes from GMT) for the target times,
        // or null for client local
```

If you need the server timezone, you'll need to muck about with PHP and find it out like that. Then you'll need to find the difference from the client timezone on the client side and put that difference as the attribute. Be weary of summer time and such.

Comment: thanks Chris, however it still counts the time from the current server time and not the time you entered for the untilYear. I tried that before but it always started from the current server time to the sinceYear time. Is there another solution you think ? Can't get it work.

Comment: hmm...Well, it still counts from the current server time. Thanks for you help Chris. I try to find the solution, but in case you got it figured it out, please share, so can be wiser of this issue ;-)